# setting input in an associate array then loop through the entries

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array that's being populated by user input. I then set that array as a session variable so that I can add on top of the array every time new input is entered.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<h1>
    <?php 
        foreach ($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'] as $x => $xValue) {
            echo $x . $xValue;
        }
    ?>
</h1>
<form action="send.php" method="post" name="form-one">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
    session_start();
    try {
        if (!empty($_POST['form-one'])) {
            $variableOne = $_POST['name'];
            $variableTwo = $_POST['number'];

            $formOneArray[$variableOne] = $variableTwo;

            $_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'] = $formOneArray;

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is your session start ? Why do you have this code in a try block? Do you have a custom error handler, which converts fatal errors into exceptions ?

Comment: my bad, I forgot to put that in my code on here. It is in my actual code though. I'll go ahead and edit this.

Comment: Why you have there session_start() twice? You tried to go through array when doesn't exist - check is using `isset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put check for first time if there is no data in `$_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal']`

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal']) && !empty($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'])){ 
             foreach ($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'] as $x => $xValue) {
                echo $x . $xValue;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather check directly that the value of your stored variable is really an array. Just checking if it is not empty will not really help you, if it were a string for example you'd still get your warning.

```
if (is_array($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['formOneArrayGlobal'] as $x => $xValue) {
        echo $x . $xValue;
    }
}
```